# How to recognize slugified values in yii routing

Tags: php, yii, url-routing

I added this route to the rules array in the main config.

```
group/<id:\d+>/<name:\w+>' => 'group/index',

public function actionIndex($id, $name)
{
   $this->render('index');
}
```

When i goto the address /group/1/nameofgroup it works great, but when I try to goto the route /group/1/name-of-group I immediately get the error:

Error 404
The system is unable to find the requested action "1".

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this issue, I wish there was a page that showed how to do routing clearly.

```
'group/<id:\d+>/<name:[\w-]+>' => 'group/index',
```

was the correct pattern.

Answer (score 1):

The - in `name-of-group` is not matched by `\w`, therefore the request is not directed to this route.